# Why can I not show my date property as a date picker in my filter list widget in Workshop?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

I have two different workshops with filter lists. In both, I am adding a filter on a date property (called “Datum” but from different object types). In one filter list, I get three different filter options: Timeline, Date range picker and Single date picker. In the other one, I don’t get any and it shows up as a timeline. Both properties are of type date and have the same format (`YYYY-MM-DD`).

How can I get the the date picker options in the filter list in my other workshop app?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you have to add the type classes ‘selectable’ and ‘sortable’ to the date property of your object type.
[image]